How to increase the Transaction Fee on SolNet (.net)
Everything has been working fine until this morning. Now my transactions broadcast successfully, but show up empty in the tracker and all calls to GetTransactionAsync return with error "Something wrong happened".
I am using SolNet, the .net library to interact with the Solana RPC and I dont see any way of increasing the transaction fee in the documentation. Would increasing the transaction fee solve this problem? Or is this a congestion situation with the whole blockchain?
I have temporarily implemented a retry functionality where transactions are considered timedout after 3.5 minutes, but they seem to be failing 99% of the time, so every transaction is still taking alot of time to finish.

You can use the ComputeBudgetProgram to set a priority fee in the UnitySDK. I assume the same will work in native solnet as well:
private void AddPriorityFee(Transaction tx)
{
    tx.Add(ComputeBudgetProgram.SetComputeUnitPrice(10000));
}

To figure out the right values you can follow this guide for example:
https://solana.com/de/developers/guides/advanced/how-to-use-priority-fees

Thank you for this answer, it put me on the right path. I realized I was using the old SolNet that is being replaced by Bifrost's Solana nuget package, this newer version has priority fees and more recent features.
